# 404 - File or directory not found. vuejs 3 and plesk

Tags: vue.js, plesk

I have developed a SPA with Vuejs and published the **"dist"** folder on **Plesk** server. But when I refresh on any route, it is showing **"404 - File or directory not found"** on browser.

I have include .htaccess file on root directory with the content from [History mode - vuejs documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations), but no luck :(

My .htaccess file looks like below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried [this](https://gist.github.com/davemackintosh/8ac35fff747dbf2c95e1) solution as well, but it didn't resolve my issue. Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#apache

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But that doesn't work for me